# How do I change the highlightShape property of a Flutter InkWell?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following Flutter widget:

```
return SizedBox(
  height: 40.0,
  width: 40.0,
  child: InkWell(
    splashColor: Colors.grey,
    onTap: callback,
    child: Center(child: image),
  ),
);
```

The problem is that the highlight on this button is rectangular. I would like to change it to a circle, but the `highlightShape` property is not available for modification. How can this button be given a circular highlight?

Comment: Have you tried [ClipRRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html) to clip your shape? This will change not only highlightShape but also widget's shape, but this is the only thing I could provide.

Comment: you have `customBorder` property for that

Comment: Thanks @pskink - `customBorder` worked for me. If you want to put it in an answer it might help others.

Comment: sure, your welcome, feel free to post a "self answer" ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @pskink's comment, I used `customBorder`:

```
return SizedBox(
  height: 40.0,
  width: 40.0,
  child: InkWell(
    splashColor: Colors.grey,
    onTap: callback,
    child: Center(child: image),
    customBorder: CircleBorder(),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    return ClipOval(
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.blue, // button color
        child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
        child: SizedBox(width: 56, height: 56, child: Icon(Icons.settings)),
        onTap: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ClipOval](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipOval-class.html) to achieve this

```
ClipOval(
      child: Material(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 40.0,
          width: 40.0,
          child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.grey,
            onTap: () {},
            child: Center(child: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```